# IIS 7 and PHP - Problem with remote access

Tags: php, iis

After ten years of ASP.net development (i.e. I know very little about PHP), I have just installed my first PHP web site running on a Windows Server 2008 R2 IIS 7.5 web server.

The web server is one of three servers running in a small network.

I have set up DNS to reference the web server.

If I open a browser on any of the local network machines and enter the url, the web site opens and runs perfectly.

If I do the same thing with a PC that is not part of the network I am unable to open the web site.

I'm not sure if this is a PHP or IIS problem (or maybe both).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be very surprised if it is a PHP problem. I have found some **very** odd behaviour in IIS with it apparently tunelling NTLM authentication to access resources on network drives, but you need to start by looking at the simple things first.

Can you access static content on the webserver? If not then you need to have a look at how your DNS, network routing and firewalls are configured.

If you can access static content but not PHP content, then the webserver should be lofgging the reason why it's turning down requests for PHP files - go read your logs.

Comment: I'm an idiot! In my anxiety over PHP I had overlooked the obvious - firewall was blocking port 80!